# How to serve static file dynamically using Next.js?

Tags: next.js

As the title of the question, how to serve static file in Next.js but not from `public` folder. This image is generated on the fly using another third-party service. I need to check authorization and download the file using the third-party service API and then serve it.

Comment: Make a route in the api folder that responds to GET requests and serves a file.

Comment: @kellys Is there a way to get rid of `/api` prefix with this approach? Can `middleware` be used to do that?

Comment: You can use [`rewrites`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites) to map whatever path you want to the `/api/*` path.